# Auto-loading Emacs themes in daemon mode

Tags: emacs, themes

I run emacs like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/emacsclient -q -a "" -t
```

and I have this in my .emacs:

```
;; ;; Theme
;; (if (daemonp)
;;     (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
;;            (lambda (frame)
;;              (message "Hello")
;;              (load-theme 'solarized-dark)))
;;   (load-theme 'solarized-dark t))
(load-theme 'solarized-dark t t)
```

This works when starting /usr/bin/emacs but not in daemon mode. As you can see from the commented lines, I've tried a few variations to get this working. I'm a beginner at emacs-lisp.

Manually running load-theme solarized-dark gets it working for all clients.